# MySQL working through LOCALHOST but connection refused through IP

Tags: php, mysql, hosting, cpanel

On my Web Hosting,MySQL working perfectly fine when connecting to it trough the localhost. But when I try to introduce the IP of the hosting it just gives me this error: 
  `Connection Refused.` This happens when I enter the site.
  I checked the Remote Connection and all that stuff and everything is working fine.

Comment: did you use the MySQL config provided by the hosting?

Comment: you better take it up with your domain provider. MySQL IP connections are generally restricted for security purpose and needs to be white listed through settings.

Comment: I spoke with them but they told me that the external connections are allowed. :(

Comment: can you share some code with us?

Comment: Yeah sure, but before all this it worked just fine I don't thing it's from PHP cuz my SA:MP server can't get to the database either.

Comment: Try login to that using command line. Maybe the IP you used is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

If your hosting is cPanel based and they allow remote MySQL connection, you should make sure that on the server which hosts the databse you have allowed a connection fromn the IP address hosting the website,meaning:

If your website is hosted on IP 11.11.11.1 and your database is hosted on a server with IP 22.22.22.2 you should login to the cPanel of the server 22.22.22.2 and allow Remote mysql connection for the IP 11.11.11.1 . This way the website will be able to connect to the databse successfully.